# Users fail to authenticate into Sharepoint 2010 when there are accent marks in the Lotus Notes user name

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Our Sharepoint users use their email address and Lotus Notes password to log in.  This is working just fine except for one case: if their Lotus Notes user name contains an accent mark, the authentication fails.

I logged LDAP activity in Notes and see it failing.  Here's an example:

```
The actual username is: René Testing/Employee/LW-US
```

What the activity log shows LDAP is receiving.

```
User Name:  CN=RenÃ© Testing/OU=Employee/O=LW-US
```

Any ideas on how to debug the problem?

thanks
clem

Comment: This question belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi Rich. Ok.  thanks.  Never heard of it but will check it out.